# access user's information using token

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Djoser for authentication in django. I have a model class called wallet which looks like following:

```
from django.db import models


class Wallet(models.Model):
    account_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name='account_no', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Wallet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then i have serializer class for this model which looks like following.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from wallet.models import Wallet


class WalletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Wallet
        fields = ('url', 'account_address', 'user')
```

I want to write an api_view for this model class with get method that returns the wallet address for a particular user. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
class WalletView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):     
        user = self.kwargs['user_id']
        return Wallet.objects 
                        .filter(Q(user__id=user))
```

**not tested